# Localization of a finitely generated module is nonzero iff the anihilator is contained in the prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]

I'm a bit stuck on both directions.

I think I need to use the fact that M is finitely generated and maybe find a way to show each of the generators is killed by everything and that would imply $M_p$ is infact 0?

https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/363/docs/F17_510ab.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us recall the definition of $M_P$. Given an $R$-module $M$, and a prime ideal $P \subset R$, we define the multiplicative set (contains $1$ and closed under multiplication) $S = R-P$. The localization of $M$ at the prime ideal $P$ denoted as $M_P$ is a set of equivalent classes of the form $\frac{m}{s}$ where $m\in M$ and $s\in S$, and 
$$\frac{m}{s} \sim \frac{n}{t}$$
if there exists a $c\in S$ such that 
$$tcm = scn \quad \text{ in } M.$$

$(\Rightarrow)$ By contrapositive, if $Ann(M)$ is not contained in $P$, so there exists some $Ann(M) \ni r\in R-P = :S$.  Now given any $\frac{m}{s}$ where $m\in M$ and $s\in S$, we will show 
$$\frac{m}{s} \sim \frac{0}{1} \quad \text{ this is the zero element in $M_P$ }.$$
To show this, we will show there exists a $c\in S$ such that $cm = s0= 0$ in $M$, just take $c = r\in Ann(M)$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Again by contrapositive, suppose $M_P = 0$, this means for each generator of $M$, call it $m_i$, we must have 
$$\frac{m_i}{1} \sim \frac{0}{1}$$
this means there exists a $c_i\in S$ such that $c_im_i = 0$ in $M$. Since $M$ is finitely generated, then $Ann(M) \ni \prod_i c_i \in S$, so $Ann(M)$ is not contained in $P$.

(So the above proof is basically showed "$M_P = 0$ if and only if $Ann(M)\not\subset P$.)

Comment: Your proof makes sense, I can't see where we'd need the f.g. condition either.

Comment: @BobbyJones: here is the error in Xiao's proof. He asserts in that if $M_{P} = 0$, for each $m \in M$, there exists $c \in S$ such that $cm = 0$. This is fine, but that does NOT mean that $c$ is in the annihilator of $M$; remember, if $c$ is in the annihilator of $M$, then $c$ must kill ALL elements of $M$, not just $m$. (The given $c \in S$ depends on $m$; we must find a way to produce a single $c$ which works for all $m$.) Here is how to fix it, and why the finitely-generated hypothesis is necessary:

Comment: Let $m_{1}, \ldots, m_{n}$ generate $M$ as an $R$-module. As (correctly) noted in the above proof, there exists $c_{i} \in S$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$ such that $c_{i}m = 0$. Then $c = c_{1}c_{2} \cdots c_{n} \in S$ (since $S$ is multiplicatively closed), and $cm_{i} = 0$ for each $i$. Since every element of $M$ is expressible as an $R$-linear combination of $m_{1}, \ldots, m_{n}$, $c$ annihilates every element of $M$.

Comment: Better to break this up into two parts: first show that the annihilator of a _finitely generated_ module is compatible with localization (just unwinding definitions), then conclude. More powerful and easier to remember.